# Sort random numbers without using any sorting functions

Tags: python, sorting

I have created a code with Python ,can anyone show me the algorithm of sorting  random numbers without using `sort()` ?

```
import random

firstNum=1
lastNum=30

range=xrange(firstNum,(lastNum))

count=20

print"Random numbers generated:"

numberlist=random.sample(range,count)
print "Before" , numberlist
print('')
numberlist.sort()
print "After" ,numberlist
print('')
```

Comment: So whats wrong with your code?

Comment: Why would you "sort without using `sort`" ? To understand the algorithm behind it, to avoid a faulty function ?

Comment: @Jiby - this is usually an interview style question... Not too sure in this case. But you have a very valid question in your comment...

Comment: First hit on google for "python sorting algorithm" http://danishmujeeb.com/blog/2014/01/basic-sorting-algorithms-implemented-in-python

Comment: @Kasramvd It's nothing wrong with the code , but I am trying to sort the random numbers in the "numberlist" without using .sort()

Comment: @EllosLai - you are ignoring a very very useful function by not using `sort()` - could you please explain why this constraint exists?

Comment: @I just want to know the method of sorting random numbers without using the code .sort()

Comment: @EllosLai - yes... you have said this already... I'm asking why you are choosing not to use built-in functionality...

Comment: @I know .sort() is useful ,but this was one of the homework of me today,and it is challenging  ,I need help guys .

Comment: May be just maybe it is an assignment :P

Comment: @EllosLai - that's exactly the point I was getting at. You need to disclose the fact that this is a homework assignment - otherwise you are just asking people to do your work for you. Rather than that - ask people for assistance - they will help you learn - and that's the goal here...right?

Comment: @Lix I am sorry but I literally have no clue on this ,I don't even know where to start ,I will look at the examples here as a references and do it.

Comment: Why do you use SO when there are websites such as [sorting-algorithms.com](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com)?

Comment: At a very, very, basic level. Sort = Work through list of elements, compare neighboring elements and swap if in the wrong order, repeat until all elements in desired order. That's actually very easy to do. What is harder is doing it efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just use `sorted`:

```
import random

firstNum = 1
lastNum = 30

range = xrange(firstNum, lastNum)

count = 20

print "Random numbers generated:"

numberlist = random.sample(range, count)
print "Before", numberlist
print('')
numberlist = sorted(numberlist)
print "After", numberlist
print('')
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the point here is not to use any sorting functions...but...hey...specifics :P

Comment: @Lix ya ,without any sorting functions .

Comment: @rightfold thanks for helping me ,but I need to sort the random numbers without any sorting function .

Comment: @EllosLai - you need to mention this in your question. Don't just refer to the specific `sort()` function. You should specify `"no built-in sorting functions."`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this different type of sorting technique. This technique called `Bubble Sort` and complexity O(n^2)

```
def bubbleSort(a):
    update=True
    while(update):
        update = False
        for i in range(len(a)-1):
            if a[i]>a[i+1]:
                a[i],a[i+1]=a[i+1],a[i]
                update = True
    return a
```

You can also use complexity `O(nlogn)` by quick sort technique. Details explanation is here [Quick Sort](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheQuickSort.html)

```
def quickSort(alist):
   quickSortHelper(alist,0,len(alist)-1)

def quickSortHelper(alist,first,last):
   if first<last:

       splitpoint = partition(alist,first,last)

       quickSortHelper(alist,first,splitpoint-1)
       quickSortHelper(alist,splitpoint+1,last)


def partition(alist,first,last):
   pivotvalue = alist[first]

   leftmark = first+1
   rightmark = last

   done = False
   while not done:

       while leftmark <= rightmark and \
               alist[leftmark] <= pivotvalue:
           leftmark = leftmark + 1

       while alist[rightmark] >= pivotvalue and \
               rightmark >= leftmark:
           rightmark = rightmark -1

       if rightmark < leftmark:
           done = True
       else:
           temp = alist[leftmark]
           alist[leftmark] = alist[rightmark]
           alist[rightmark] = temp

   temp = alist[first]
   alist[first] = alist[rightmark]
   alist[rightmark] = temp


   return rightmark

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
quickSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code ,but can you give some simple explanation on this ,I appreciate that .

Comment: @Ellos Lai this is a well known sorting technique.please follow this link. I think you understand. If you don't understand, then i will explain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: my attempt to sort random numbers with bubbersort,but it is not working

Comment: import random

firstNum=1
lastNum=30


range=xrange(firstNum,(lastNum))

count=20
numberlist=random.sample(range,count)


def shortBubbleSort(alist):
    exchanges = True
    passnum = len(alist)-1
    while passnum > 0 and exchanges:
       exchanges = False
       for i in range(passnum):
           if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
               exchanges = True
               temp = alist[i]
               alist[i] = alist[i+1]
               alist[i+1] = temp
       passnum = passnum-1

alist=[numberlist]
shortBubbleSort(alist)
print(alist)

Answer (score 0):

There is a wide variety of different sorting implementations. The difference of them lies in their space and time **complexity** and their side benefits.

This question is too general to give a good specific answer, but we can give you some directions.

Consider looking into:

- Bubble sort
- Merge sort
- Insertion sort
- Quick sort
- Heap sort

Consider taking a look at this [link](http://danishmujeeb.com/blog/2014/01/basic-sorting-algorithms-implemented-in-python), which gives a good introduction to basic python sorting algorithms or use the search function on Stack Overflow to find more information about these algorithms.